# Consuming Web Service from C++/CLI

Tags: c#, web-services, c++-cli

is it possible to consume web service (written in c#, ... I don't have control over it, just URL to it's .asmx) from C++/CLI? There is no 'add web reference' in C++/CLI project :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. if you want to do it simply just create a proxy dll in C# (add web reference) and then consume  those assemblies, or you can hand code the proxy in C++/CLI.

Edit to reflect comment.

You can use [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) to merge multiple assemblies into one if need be.

> ILMerge takes a set of input
>   assemblies and merges them into one
>   target assembly.

Comment: Sounds like the only way.. Althrough I wanted to distribute only one executable, not DLLs with it.

Answer (score 4):

M$ removes "add web references.." and similars older useful features for c++ projects (nice!!! very nice Mr. Bill ;) )
You still can to use wsdl /language:cpp  that generate a .h file with all the proxy contract services, next, you should add the . generated .h file to project. See the .h file, find the desired web method to use and get an instance from the desired class using **gcnew**